# Looping over lines in a file and creating multiple directory

Tags: python

I am trying to loop over the lines in a file and create multiple directories. My script is working only for the first line of list in a file. Here is my script. I have attached image of list as well. That is for both `list_bottom.dat` and `list_top.dat`.

```
import os
f = open("list_top.dat", "r")
g = open("list_bottom.dat", "r")
for lines in f:
    m_top = lines.split()[0]

    m_bot = lines.split()[0]
    os.mkdir(m_top)
    os.chdir(m_top)
    for lines in g:
        print(lines)
        m_bot = lines.split()[0]
        print(m_bot)
        os.mkdir(m_top + "_" + m_bot)
        os.chdir(m_top + "_" + m_bot)
        for angle in range(5):
              os.mkdir(m_top + "_" + "m_bot" + "_angle_" + str(angle))
              os.chdir(m_top + "_" + "m_bot" + "_angle_" + str(angle))
              os.chdir("../")
        os.chdir("../")

    os.chdir("../")
os.chdir("../")
```

[image]

Comment: could you add an example of the lines stored in the files ? or better : just change the example by creating a list of the strings as they are read

Comment: (please check how the code is indented in your question to reflect your own code, not sure about the edits)

Comment: Hi, PRMoureu, Thank you for your response. Actually I wanted to create folders inside the folder with name as first line and so on. I have attached a screenshot of the folders I got from  the script. I want to have that for second line, third line as well. I think the problem is some how related to change in change in directory, but did not find where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to read from a file pointer, not from its content. you should do this instead

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    do_stuff()
```

(for readability i don't post this as a comment, but that's a comment)

Comment: Great, Thank you so much. I got it.